# Jquery on a hierarchial or nested list containing <a> tags

Tags: jquery, html-lists, hierarchical-data, nested-lists

How would you appropriately code the jquery for the below list containing the `<a>` tags. I'm having two problems.

1. When I click the parent list item to reveal the child item, the parent item disappears and is simply replaced by an indented child item on the same line.
2. Somewhat related, I can for some reason click the last element of "1" "2" "3" and "4" resulting in the list actually disappearing. How can i fix this problem?

HTML:

```
<div class="main_list">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">1.</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">1.1</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#">1.1.1</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     <li><a href="#">2.</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">3.</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
       </ul>
     <li><a href="#">4.</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">4.1</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#">4.1.1 </a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4.1.2 </a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// only show top level elements to begin
$("ul ul").hide();


$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).children().toggle(500);
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `children("ul")` to only toggle the `ul` children of the parent item `li`. Otherwise, you'll toggle the parent item, `<a href="#">1.</a>`, which is also a child of `li`:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).children("ul").toggle(500);
    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PEFyh/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done complete sample bins for above query. instead of return false, we should use Jquery's event object method "stopPropagation()" which stops hierarchical event occurrence.

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7e

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        1.
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            1.1
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                1.1.1
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          2.
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        3.
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            3.1
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            3.2
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          4.
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              4.1
            </a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  4.1.1 
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  4.1.2 
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    // only show top level elements to begin
    $("ul ul").hide();

    $("li").click(function(e) {
        //need to change here...
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).children("ul").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
li{
  list-style:none;
}
ul{
  margin:5px;
  padding:2px;
}
```

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7e